# sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type <class 'sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.engine.AsyncEngine'>

Tags: sqlalchemy

I followed this example but with aiosqlite: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/metadata.html#table-reflection

like:

```py
import asyncio

from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession

from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String

metadata = MetaData()

engine = create_async_engine(
        "sqlite+aiosqlite:////Users/rui/database.db",
        echo=True,
        future=True,
    )

    # Table Reflection (Loading existing table)
    users = Table("users", metadata, autoload_with=engine)
```

Then I'm having this error:

```
File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/playground/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 298, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/playground/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 597, in __new__
    metadata._remove_table(name, schema)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/playground/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/playground/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/playground/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 592, in __new__
    table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/playground/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 667, in _init
    self._autoload(
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/playground/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 700, in _autoload
    insp = inspection.inspect(autoload_with)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/playground/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/inspection.py", line 71, in inspect
    raise exc.NoInspectionAvailable(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type <class 'sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.engine.AsyncEngine'>
python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm using Python 3.9.2, sqlalchemy==1.4.5 and aiosqlite==0.17.0

Should I replace `aiosqlite` by another one? Or should I wait until asyncio will be improved in sqlalchemy?

Comment: @snakecharmerb [that example](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5920) does not use "Table reflection" (`autoload_with=engine`). That example also works for me, but with reflections not. I just created a bug issue here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/6191 . Thanks